# How to add and delete row in a table simultaneously in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app in that I have created a 4x4 table.I've written code to add a table row:-

```
var row = table.insertRow(rows.length);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
```

To delete the row , my code is :

```
$('#rowid')
.children('td')
.animate({
    height: 0
},205,'')
.wrapInner('<div />')
.children()
.slideUp({
    duration: 205, 
    easing: '', complete: function()
    {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

In the app, user can see 4 rows at a time. when the user clicks on a colored cell, one row will be deleted from top and one new row will be added in bottom. 
If he keeps on clicking on colored cell, then with the above process it should give a scrolling kind of effect to the user.
But with the above code, that sliding up effect is not smooth.

Please tell how to speed up the scrolling effect and make it look like continuous.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to animate table elements.
If you're not forced to use a TABLE a UL would make your life a lot easier.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/minekaquye/1/edit?js,output

Is this the effect you're looking for?

HTML:

```
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="list__element">Element</li>
    <li class="list__element">Element</li>
    <li class="list__element">Element</li>
    <li class="list__element">Element</li>    
  </ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.list__element').on('click', modifyList);

function modifyList(e) {

  // Delete li
  deleteRow('.list__element:first-child');

  // Add a new li
  addRow('.list');

}


function deleteRow(target) {

  $(target).slideUp(300, function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });  

}

function addRow(target) {

  var $target = $(target),
      html = '<li class="list__element" style="display:none;">Element</li>';

  $target
    .append(html)
    .find('li:last-child')
    .on('click', modifyList)
    .slideDown(300);

}
```

CSS:

```
.list {
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.list__element {
  background-color:#CCC;
  padding:10px;
}

.list__element:first-child {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this effect I am getting from my code as well. The effect which I want is to make this scrolling faster and continuous, the scrolling should not stop after the user's click. Once the user clicked on a cell of the table scrolling(deletion and addition of rows) should keep on happening, it should not stop. For reference please check the arcade mode of PianoTiles game in android.